# Windows Sandbox got broken

Tags: windows-sandbox

I sometimes use Windows Sandbox to test softwares.

After the latest Windows update, it got broken.

When it starts, the Explorer in the Sandbox keeps restarting and I have a lot of errors in the Event Viewer.

[image]

My host Windows 11 works properly.
I tried to disable and re-enable the Sandbox service, nothing changed.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify what relevance the bullet points following the screenshot have to do with your question? Are you simply trying to inform us what Sandbox is? Or is that information you've found in the error logs somewhere? Or something else? If you're just trying to help us understand what Sandbox is, please remove that, as Sandbox is a well documented feature of Windows and those lines distract from the actual problem.

Comment: Have you tried rolling back your Windows to prior to the patches that installed? Did you check to see if any of the patches have any impact on Sandbox? While Explorer restarts, does the Sandbox actually run?

Comment: @music2myear The bullet points meant to emphasize the controverse of the pristine and working state and the compromised current state. This theoritically can't happen yet here we are....

Comment: I have removed that unnecessary aside. While you do state that your "... host Windows 11 works properly", you do not actually state whether it is the Sandbox Explorer.exe or host Explorer.exe that is crashing.

Comment: I've clarified it a bit more.

Comment: I have a Windows 11 Pro Insider machine (CPU too old to run Production Windows 11).  This machine has been running Hyper-V for some time. I turned on Sandbox and let it restart.  It is working properly (I have used it before on a different machine as well).  Windows 11 22H2 22621.2500

Comment: @John - Your using have a preview cumulative update installed. The fact Sandbox works on your system doesn’t eliminate the possibility this is an actual issue with the update the author has installed

Comment: I am using a very conservative preview build and it is almost identical to my production machine build. I also note I have used Sandbox successfully on another machine. So I do not think this is a Sandbox issue.

Comment: @John- The issue is 22H2 and 23H2 are both 22621 and installed. Haven’t determined how you determine if the enablement package has been installed but *.2500 is a Release Channel build.

Comment: Yes but my production machine is .2400 something. Very close and none of my machines are 23H2 (still not out to most people). So I continue to think Sandbox itself is working fine.  All optional updates done on all machines.  If I knew, I would post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that lots of other users struggle with this problem after [a not so successful Windows update](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-sandbox-does-not-open-file-explorer/bd04adf1-cbd1-4674-b224-9560b4cbecae)

We have to wait for a patch to get it fixed.

EDIT:

It seems that *no patch will be created*, so you have to do a workaround to get it working:

> Create a text file that you rename to sandbox.wsb afterwards. The
> content of the file must contain the following:
>
> ```
> <Configuration>
>   <MappedFolders>
>     <MappedFolder>
>       <HostFolder>C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.CBS_8wekyb3d8bbwe</HostFolder>
>       <SandboxFolder>C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.CBS_8wekyb3d8bbwe</SandboxFolder>
>       <ReadOnly>true</ReadOnly>
>     </MappedFolder>
>   </MappedFolders>
> </Configuration>
> ```